# How to adjust the following block diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

I'm starting to use the package of [schemablocks](https://ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc), but I can't accomplish the next graph

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{schemabloc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbEntree{X} 
%\sbComp*{C1}{X}     \sbRelier[X]{X}{C1}
\sbComp{C2}{X}     \sbRelier[X]{X}{C2}
\sbBlocL{F}{$\frac{K}{J\cdot s+a}$}{C2}
\sbRelier[Y]{Y}{}
\sbBlocL[6]{int}{$\frac{1}{s}$}{F}
\sbSortie[6]{Y}{int}
\sbRelier[Y]{}{}
      %\sbRelier[Y]{int}{F} %\sbRelier[Y]{int}{Y}

\sbDecaleNoeudy{F}{R}
\sbBlocr[-2]{R}{$K_f$}{R}   
\sbRelieryx{F-int}{R}
\sbRelierxy{R}{C2}
%\sbRenvoi[6]{int-Y}{C1}{text}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Giving the next output
[image]

But how can put the Y as caption, between the $\frac{K}{Js+a}$ ?
I don't clearly understand how to reference the nodes.

Comment: I was not able to make your code compile. Did you get any output with it? And your question is not clear to me. Where do you want this Y exactly?

Comment: It is not clear for me where you want the "Y". What do you mean by "between the $\frac{K}{Js+a}$ "?

Comment: I want the "Y" appears where the feedback line starts.

Comment: I dont understand well how it works even reading the documentation and following the examples there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if I don't really understand the purpose of this scheme, I recreated it from scratch to avoid some errors that made your code not compilable. Feel free to ask for improvements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{schemabloc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \sbEntree{E}
        \sbComp{comp}{E}
        \sbRelier[$X$]{E}{comp}
        \sbBloc{F}{$\frac{K}{J\cdot s+a}$}{comp}
        \sbRelier[$Y$]{comp}{F}
        \sbBloc[6]{int}{$\frac{1}{s}$}{F}
        \sbRelier{F}{int}
        \sbDecaleNoeudy[4]{F}{U}
        \sbBlocr[-2]{R}{$K_f$}{U}
        \sbRelieryx{F-int}{R}
        \sbRelierxy{R}{comp}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: schemabloc]